# jQuery UI isn't working properly on my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

So I just started getting into jQuery in a web developer course online and I'm starting to use jQuery UI but when I followed the steps on how to set it up in the video it doesn't work. I tried to put a draggable into my text editor and it doesn't even pop up. I tried changing the directory of the links in order to put in something like a draggable, and I tried messing around with little errors that I could've made with my code and nothing seems to be working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated in helping me to figure out what is wrong. This is the code for my webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#draggable").draggable();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have a `draggable` element defined on your page. Try adding that element.

Comment: Your document's `<body>` has not a single element besides that script. Try adding `<p id="draggable">Drag me</p>` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a CDN for jQuery itself, you might try doing the same with jQueryUI and its styles. This will at least eliminate one possible cause of confusion.

Replace:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

With:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
```

You can change out the stylesheet href with one of the themes on the jQuery UI downloads page: https://code.jquery.com/ui/

Then you need to add draggable content and add `draggable()` on page ready by wrapping it in jQuery's `$();`.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

  ...

  <script>
    $( function() {
      $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    } );
  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

For more information, see: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Did that help or are you still having issues with your code?